# C - Read file line by line ignoring leading and trailing whitespaces assigning values by a certain format

Tags: c

I am trying to read a file line by line and take the two separate string and assign them to two different variable. There will be an unknown amount of white space before and after.

I am given a file like:

```
EXAMPLE.TXT
===========
company value\n
     company value    \n
company value   \n
```

There can be any sort of white space characters before `<company>` or after `<value>`, but there will always be only one space between the two. I am trying to take these `<company>` and `<values>` and put them into a hashtable. This is how I am doing it right now.

```
hashtable_t * accounts = create_hashtable(lines);
//Inserting into hashtable
while(fscanf(fd, " <%79[^>]> <%lf%*[^\n]", company, &balance) == 2) {
      if(set(accounts, company, balance) == 0) {
            continue;
      } else {
            return NULL;
      }
}

fclose(fd);
return accounts;
```

I think my issue is in the parameter of the while loop. It is returning -1, so I assume that isn't valid parameters.

Comment: What is your question?   And if your code is not doing what you expect then explain what it is doing

Comment: `fscanf` returning `-1` means you are at the end of the file already (or the file failed to open)

Comment: @M.M I updated the OP. I am trying to read from a file and take the two strings in the line and assign them to two variables. The fscanf(fd, " <%79[^>]> <%lf%*[^\n]", company, &balance) returns -1, so theres an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fscanf` returns EOF when the end of file is reached or a read error is occurred.
Since your case is it returns -1, I suggest check out the `ferror`:

```
int err = ferror(fd);
fprintf(stderr, "err %d: %s\n", err, strerror(err));
```

My test of the scanf shows it works:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    char line[256];

    int lines = 0;

    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, fp) != NULL)
            ++lines;

    printf("total lines: %d\n", lines);

    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);

    double balance;
    char company[128] = {'\0'};
    int ret;

    while ((ret = fscanf(fp, " <%[^>]> <%lf>", company, &balance)) == 2) {
            printf("%s: %lf\n", company, balance);
    }
    if (!feof(fp)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "error %d\n", ferror(fp));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

test file:

```
 <Company> <33.44>
    <cOmpany> <34.44>
         <coMpany> <35.44>
         <comPany> <36.44>
```

output:

```
total lines: 4
Company: 33.440000
cOmpany: 34.440000
coMpany: 35.440000
comPany: 36.440000
```

Comment: In a scanf string, a space means "match zero or more whitespace characters"

Comment: updated my answer since op updated the question, it's not about fscanf has wrong matches, rather it failed.

Comment: @fluter I think my issue before was that I had previously scanned the file to count the number of lines in the file. I am now using the rewind(fd) function to go to the top. I'm still having trouble. The solution you originally suggested is returning 0.

Comment: @notacodemonkey ok, I suggest check against eof and errors, see my test above.

Comment: @fluter I think I might not have been clear in my original post. The file wont have <>, I was just using those to signify that the company and would be different each time. Sorry about that. My fault. I took off the carrots from your reply and I think the double is getting assigned, but the string is having issues so the fscanf is returning 1, not 2. Thanks!

Comment: @notacodemonkey How about the value, will it enclosed in < and >?

Comment: @fluter No. There are no < > enclosures. I updated the OP to reflect what the file will look like. Again, I'm sorry about that.

Comment: @notacodemonkey In that case, it would be even simpler, just change the format to `fscanf(fp, " %s %lf", company, &balance))`. :)